# Package manager console in VS 2017 cannot run exe file located in %windir%\system32

Tags: visual-studio-2017, package-manager-console

A `hello world` `C#` `x64` application created in `Visual Studio 2017` is executed successfully via `Package Manager Console` (`PMC`) everywhere else except `%windir%\system32` location. The strange thing is that it is executed in Windows `PowerShell` (not as `admin`) but not from `PMC` in Visual Studio 2017. I thought it was an issue of the execution policy, but it was not.

I changed the execution policy in `PMC` to match the windows `PowerShell` execution policy, but it didn't make any difference.

I also executed the command `Set-Location $env:windir\system32` and then `Get-Location` to confirm it, but it had no effect. Any ideas?

System: `win7x64`
`Visual Studio 2017 15.6.0`

Comment: Is it 32-bit?  The 32-on-64 directory aliasing might mean you're using the wrong folder.

Comment: No it is `64-bit` (in build options i deselect `prefer 32-bit`). I also confirmed it from task manager (it is not marked as `*32`). Anyway, if you try to run `32-bit` `exe` located in `%windir%\system32`, via `cmd` or `PowerShell`, it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Actually i had to do exactly the opposite. `Visual Studio` is `32-bit` and therefore `prefer 32-bit` option must be selected in the executable build options in `C#`. Then the executable must be stored in `%windir%\syswow64` and everything works fine.